# Javascript on function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

My client's webshop has a custom product configurator which has a `window.build_preview` function.

This method can be called whenever, but I want to check when it's called.
jQuery has an `.on` method, but it only applies to DOM eventlisteners.

Is it possible to listen for function calls in JS?
For example:

```
$(window).on(build_preview(), function() {
   alert('Function has been called somewhere else!');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and dispatch a custom event

```
const event = new Event('build_preview');

// Listen for the event.
window.addEventListener('build_preview', 
    function (e) { 
        alert("function has been called somewhere else") 
    },
    false);

// Dispatch the event inside your function build_preview so that whenever it 
// is called this event is emitted.
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

for more info check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me.
But is there a way to pass data to the listener?

Comment: You can use custom event. See the above link you will find everything there related to custom events in js
const event = new CustomEvent('build', { detail: elem.dataset.time });

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the original function and trigger a custom event in the new version and add an event listener for the custom event.

Just make sure that the original is already declared prior to your overload code

```js
// original function declaration
window.build_preview = function(){
   console.log('.build_preview() called')
}

// store reference to original function
const origFn = window.build_preview

// overload the function
window.build_preview = function(){
   // call original
   origFn();
   // trigger custom event
   $(window).trigger('build_preview')
}
// custom event listener
$(window).on('build_preview', function(){
    console.log('event triggered from build_preview() call');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="build_preview()">Click me</button>
```